# Как запустить сайт на django? Сайт скачан с бекапа на ftp сервере

Tags: python, django

Как запустить сайт который был развернут на хостинге, после того как забрал себе не знаю как запустить, у сайта нет интерпретатора но есть виртуальное окружение.
Сейчас при запуске сайта с новым интерпретатором ошибка utf-8 синтаксис в 1 строке интерпретатора.

Comment: что значит "у сайта нет интерпритатора"?

Comment: ну его пришлось в ручную прокидать, копировать из основной папки питона. Если взять бекап из cpanel то локально на пк интерпретатора не будет в папке с виртуальной средой.

Comment: что вы называете интерпритатором? django или python? папку с виртуальной средой копировать не нужно, читайте мануалы о том, как работать с виртуальными средами в python (virtualenv).

Comment: Ну если развернуть бекап то виртуальная среда будет. интерпретатор python.exe в который нужно устанавливать все пакеты которые используются. Если в общей библиотеке нет. Для работы можно использовать и основной интерпретатор что есть на пк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в папку со средой установить или поставить python.exe то все запускается, главное все остальное доустановить.